# Issue with Numpy Concatenate?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to use numpy concatenate and am running into a strange error.

I would like to understand why this fails:

```
a = np.arange(0,3)
b = np.arange(3,6)
c = np.array([a,b])
np.concatenate(c, axis=1)
```

AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1

...but this succeeds:

```
np.concatenate([c], axis=1)
```

and also this succeeds:

```
grid = np.array([[0,1,2], [3,4,5]])
print(grid)
np.concatenate([grid,grid], axis=1)
```

Comment: What output were you hoping for from `concatenate(c, axis=1)`? And are you asking why you can't concatenate `a` and `b` on axis 1 in the first place, or why `concatenate(c, axis=1)` ends up doing the same thing as `concatenate((a, b), axis=1)`, or…?

Comment: My question is why does the first one fail? I would like the output of the first code excerpt to match the second two excerpts.

Comment: The first one fails because a and b only have a single axis. (`axis=0`)

Comment: The second one does not fail because it has two axes. (`axis=1`)

Comment: I would love to understand what are you trying to achieve with `np.concatenate(c, axis=1)`. That is, what did you expect to get as output from this command (given that input `c` is a single array)?

Comment: You could have answered the question easily by yourself if you had read the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first argument to [`concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) is a sequence of arrays. Of course a multi-dimensional array can always be treated as a sequence of arrays, so passing `c` does the same thing as passing `(a, b)` here.

So, each of the two arrays you're concatenating are 1-dimensional. You're trying to concatenate them on axis 1, an axis they don't have. Hence the error.

If you want to add an axis and concatenate along that new axis, that's [`stack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html#numpy.stack) (or `vstack` or `hstack`), not `concatenate`.

---

Meanwhile, I'm not sure what output you're trying to get, but since you've already created `c`, it's probably easier to just use it. For example:

- `stack((a, b))` or `stack(c)` or, if you insist, `concatenate([c])` will all give you `array([[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5]])`… but so will just using `c`.
- `stack((a, b), axis=1)` and so on will give you `array([[0, 3], [1, 4], [2, 5]])`, but so will `c.T`.

---

Why does `np.concatenate([c], axis=1)` succeed? Well, `[c]` is a sequence of one 2D array. Which of course has an axis 1. So it concatenates that array with nothing, and gives you back the exact same thing as `c`.

And why does `np.concatenate([grid, grid], axis=1)` succeed, where `grid` is the same 2D array as `c`? Because `[grid, grid]` is a sequence of two 2D arrays, so each one has an axis 1, so it will concatenate them together, giving you `[[0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5]]`.